Exercise 6.5 of Atiyah and Macdonald

A topological space $X$ is said to be Noetherian if the open subsets of $X$ satisfy the ascending chain condition (or, equivalently, the maximal condition). Since closed subsets are complements of open subsets, it comes to the same thing to say that the closed subsets of $X$ satisfy the descending chain condition (or, equivalently, the minimal condition). Show that, if $X$ is Noetherian, then every subspace of $X$ is Noetherian, and that $X$ is quasi-compact.

Here is a proof of $X$ is quasi-compact, using maximal condition. I was wondering if we could prove using ascending chain condition. Let $X=\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$, where $U_i$ is open subset of $X$. If $I=\Bbb{N}$, then $U_1\subseteq U_1\cup U_2\subseteq \cdots$ will do. If $I$ is uncountably infinite, for instance $I=[0,1]$, then I don’t know how to construct ascending chain, which will lead us to desired result.

You can just repeat the proof that maximal condition <=> ascending chain condition, in the special case of finite subcovers. Have you tried that?

Copying the proof of maximal condition implies ACC works. Let $\mathcal U$ be an open cover of $X$. Pick arbitrary $U_1$ in the cover. If $U_1=X$, you are done. Otherwise, find $U_2\in\mathcal{U}$ such that $U_1\subsetneq U_1\cup U_2$. Continue this way. By ACC, you must stop.
Hope this helps. :)

I think $U_2\supsetneq U_1\cup U_2$ is typo, it should have been $U_1\subsetneq U_1\cup U_2$. I knew chain $U_1\subseteq U_1\cup U_2\cdots$ stabilizes, but couldn’t show stabilizes to $X$. Suppose we have an ascending chain index by rational number between $0$ and $1$. Then it wasn’t clear that $U_{\pi -3}\subseteq U_n$ (maximal element of chain). Thinking of proof in your way makes complete sense.
